# Can't show the text in DataGridViewButtonColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

I've try to practice with "DataGridViewButtonColumn" property.

But here is a strange problem that I can't display the text in button in first column.

ScreenShot:

[image]

I try it in different methods, but it still not working.

Here is my code snippet.

Thanks ^__^

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Demo d;
        List<Demo> list = new List<Demo>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            d = new Demo();

            d.No = i.ToString();
            d.Name = "A" + i;
            list.Add(d);
        }

        foreach (Demo item in list)
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item.No, item.Name);
    }

public struct Demo
{
    public string No { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you  set the Text property to Compare and UseColumnTextForButtonValue to True,

Comment: Using the code you posted, it's working fine for me.  Do you have a minimal example to reproduce this (mis)behavior?

Comment: I've set the UseColumnTextForButtonValue = Ture, but still not working...:(

Comment: @OhBeWise What!!! I still display nothing...
My environment is VS2013 with .NET 4.5.
The whole project [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6XUuzh41uenUUlEX0hTMkxBMXc/view)

Answer (score 6):

Read up on [DataGridViewButtonColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn.usecolumntextforbuttonvalue(v=vs.110).aspx).

Set the value to `false` to get your desired results:

```
this.Column1.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = false;
```

---

Setting it to `true` means that it will use `DataGridViewButtonColumn.Text` for every button's text value (which you didn't set - and therefore shows blank text on all buttons).  For example:

```
this.Column1.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
this.Column1.Text = "Click Here";
```

[image: 10 "Click Here" buttons]